# Selectbox click not working in easyadmin with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, easyadmin

Selectbox click not working in easyadmin with javascript

```
$("#Tariff_customer_type-ts-control").click(); 
$("#Tariff_customer_type-opt-2").click();
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, do you want do use javascript to select a specific option from your select ?

Comment: There is a lack of information in your question. Try with more detail, please.

Comment: Yes. I want to choose one of two options

Answer (score 0):

You can try with "[0].click().trigger('change')" like that :

`$("#Tariff_customer_type-ts-control")[0].click().trigger('change');`

I think you are using select2 api right ?
If you try to change value of input you can use also something like this

```
$('#Tariff_customer_type-ts-control').val('Bireysel').trigger('change');
```

Or you can call a function when ever select value is changed like that :

```
  <select  style="width: 100%" onchange="my_function()"
```